Is it easier to hack all the terminals before, or after the final boss?
It seems I've been to every room on the map, but I haven't hacked every terminal. I'm at 99% and haven't beaten what looks to be the final boss, A-something.
I've heard there's a New Game Plus mode, but if I beat the final boss, can I reload at the Precipice of Eternity Sync Station right before the final boss, then get the terminals I missed, or do I have to start a new game, plus?

You can copy your save in the load game menu just in case, but beating Aphellanx doesn't alter your save file's load location, and the New Game Plus mode is a separate start menu option, so you it won't be any harder to get all the terminals after beating the Aphellanx.
